# Get Facebook access token for my own public photo album

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api

Ok I'm at a loss here, totally confused by the Facebook Graph API docs.
I have a very simple request: I want to display my own facebook photo album on an external website. The album is public to everyone, and using the Graph API Explorer I got the correct URL: https://graph.facebook.com/3605097331203/photos

If I paste this in the address bar, I get an empty JSON result. Do I need an access token to display my own public album? I know you can set up a Facebook app but that seems overkill. If there's anyone who can guide me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!
Stijn

Answer (score 0):

You need an access token or the right permissions. Check the needed permissions for the photo connection in the album object: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/